# Rails find with a condition of ID NOT IN, how to support a null value of a mapping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to show a user all groups they are currently not already a member of. The below works fine when the user is in at least one group:

```
Group.find(:all, :conditions => ['id not in (?), @groups.map(&:id)])
```

This fails when the user is in 0 groups, and `@groups.map(&:id)` is null .. How can I update the above to support the use case when @groups.map(&:id) is null/nill in ruby on rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Rails 3 includes ARel, which lets you build piecewise functions. This is super handy in this sort of circumstance.

```
scope = Group
group_ids = @groups.map(&:id)
scope = scope.where(['id not in (?)', group_ids]) unless group_ids.empty?
scope.all
```

What this'll do is only include the `NOT IN` condition if there are group IDs to exclude. When the groups to exclude is empty, it won't include that in the query.

Comment: That's exactly it. Might read easier if it was expressed as `if (group_ids.present?)` instead of a double negative.

Comment: Thanks that's cool but a lot more lines of code. still holding out for a 1 liner :)

Comment: I don't get it, Arel has nothing to do with this. Use where or find with conditions or arel tables, the problem is the same, it doesn't work with empty arrays. Writing a conditional is a common solution, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround:

```
Group.where(['id NOT IN (?)', @groups.map(&:id).presence || [0]])
```

Using Arel it works as expected, without any hacks:

```
Group.where(Group.arel_table[:id].not_in(@groups.map(&:id)))
```

Comment: not sure about rails 3+(or ruby 1.9.3+) but `[] || [0]` returns `[]`. I would do this instead: `@groups.presence.join(",")`. PS: This is for rails 2.3 and ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: @Ritikesh: `[] || [0]` returns `[]`, indeed, that's why I use presence: `[].presence || [0]` returns `[0]`.

Comment: Oh. missed the presence part. Sorry, my bad. 
Just curious, how would the actual use-case of @groups.presence returning true work out? it won't return the ids you don't want to select.

Answer (score 1):

This probably belongs in a scope:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search_excluding_ids, lambda { |g| 
      g.present? ? where(['id not in (?)', group_ids]) : {}
  }
end

Group.search_excluding_ids(ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no accepted answer to this, will post what did the trick for me on Rails 2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3:

`Group.find(:all, :conditions => ['id not in (?), @groups.map(&:id).join(",")])`